How to integrate Firebase Data Connect with Cloud Functions
Is it possible to integrate Data Connect with Cloud Functions? The only mention in the docs that comes close is this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/data-connect/admin-sdk


Hi there, did you manage to sort it out?

@CamiloCasadiego Did you have any luck getting this to work?

Integration between Firebase Database Connect and Google Cloud Functions requires two parts:

A way to call the Data Connect from within your Cloud Functions code. This is possible with the Admin SDK that you linked.

A way to trigger Cloud Functions from Data Connect events. This isn't possible yet, but it being planned. If you want to vote track or vote for this feature, you can do so here: Event Triggers.



Can one still use the generated Web SDK in a cloud function ?

In that case you won't be using the Admin SDK, but it might work. Give it a try!
